# Cannot find_package when using CMake superbuild

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to transform a non-CMake project into one: https://github.com/warrenbocphet/rplidar_sdk/tree/cmake

I have done so by using `configure_package_config_file` with the hope that it would create the config file, which will aid `find_package(rplidar_sdk)` in my own project.

But it seems like when I config rplidar as an external project (check https://github.com/warrenbocphet/tonton), it cannot find the config file at all. In fact, all the public headers I set for rplidar_sdk seems not to appear in the build tree.

Seeing other projects at also set up as an external project in my repo, I can see in the build tree, they have:

```
CLI11 (project name)
| -- include
| -- share
| -- src
| -- tmp
```

while rplidar_sdk is:

```
rplidar_sdk
| -- lib
| -- src
| -- tmp
```

Here's my CMake command for the main repo (tonton) (also put in Make file):

```
cmake -S . -B build -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF
cmake --build build --parallel 4 --config Release
cmake --install build
```

I'm fairly certain I don't have a grasp for CMake yet, but I don't know where I went wrong. I would really appreciate some pointers :).

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect relevant code to be in the **question post** itself. Links to the external repos are not sufficient. Note also, that we don't need all your code, we need [mcve].

Comment: Clearly not a cmake expert either, but at first glance it looks like you are explicitely skipping the install step for rplidar_sdk, which afaik would be where e.g. headers could get copied if needed.

Comment: Putting `project()` before `cmake_minimum_required` is a recipe for disaster...

Comment: I won't try a project downloading & building protobuf, grpc, abseil etc. All I can say is that at least https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html is missing in your fork of `rplidar_sdk` to make config file as it is written tree usable from build tree. It is also totally unusable from install tree since targets are not exported. Moreover, there shouldn't be a condition here: https://github.com/warrenbocphet/rplidar_sdk/blob/ac1965c7d6a8ee307435afcbda6cce306b6b6941/cmake/rplidar_sdk_Config.cmake.in#L3-L5, just include, and export your targets in CMakeLists